# To show the modal dialog again which is already open in PHP for validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a PHP page for insert, update and delete in which a pop up for edit  is shown as follows

[image]

The pop is shown in jquery as follows when the edit button  is clicked in the table in background of image shown according to the id:

```
 $('.edit').live('click',function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
    params={};
    params.id=id;
    params.action="editClient";
    $('#popupbox').load('chapter_manager.php', params,function(){
        $('#block').show();
        $('#popupbox').show();
           $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $("#wait").css("display", "none");
});
    })
```

I need validation for the two input boxes. With jquery it works fine .

I need to perform server side validation .

The problem is that the page gets relaoded after the button click and hence the pop is not shown again after the server side validation.

I tried ajax but not working. Any idea how should I show the pop up again?

Also I want to know whether I need to perform PHP server side validation when already I have done validation in jquery?

I am using a page template in the modal pop up with the from submit and submit button as follows which is different from the page which is seen in the background.

```
 <form name ="client" id="client" method="POST" action="chapter_manager.php"><div style="display: block; position:relative;" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:100%; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button id="close_form" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"> <?php echo $view->label ;?> </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <table>
            <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php print $view->client->getChapter_ID() ?>"> <label>Name:</label>
                <span style="color:#c30;">*</span>
                <?php /*?><span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span><?php */?>
                <span class="error"> <?php echo $nameErr;?></span> </td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value = "<?php print $view->client->getChapter_Name() ?>">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><br/>
              </td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>Description:</label>
                <span style="color:#c30;">*</span> </td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description" value = "<?php print $view->client->getChapter_Description() ?>">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <input id="cancel" class="btn btn-default pull-left" type="button" value ="Cancel" />
        <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary "  type="submit" name="submit" value ="Save Changes" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Show your popup code!!

Comment: You might be submitting the `form`.. show the code containing `modal form` and also `submit function`

Comment: Yes, you need to do server validation, since javascript can be disabled.

Comment: it is due to the load method. use ajax call.

Comment: Yes  Guruprasad Rao I am using a template with form and submit

Comment: Can you post that part?